# How to get name of the called aliased subroutine?

Tags: perl

How could I get know which alias was used to call aliased subroutine? `caller` gives the original `sub`-name, but I'd like to see name used on calling.

Example:

```
use 5.010;
sub x_y_z {
  return ( caller(0) )[3];
}

*foo_bar_baz = \&x_y_z;

say x_y_z();        # x_y_z
say foo_bar_baz();  # x_y_z, but need foo_bar_baz
```

**Edit to address XY problem**

I add another example to show my deeper intentsions. I want to create dispatch-table to route some tasks:

```
my $dispatch = {
  x => {
    y => {
      z => sub {
          &x_y_z;
      },
    }
  },
  a => {
    b => {
      c => {
        d => sub {
          &a_b_c_d;
        },
      }
    }
  }
}

sub foo {
  my @arg = ( split '_', ( split( '::', ( caller(0) )[3] ) )[1] );  
  return @arg;
}

*x_y_z = \&foo;
*a_b_c_d = \&foo;
```

As you may imagine, this tree may grow pretty big. Now many leaves in dispatch-tree needs basically same sub, they differ just how they are called (named) and I'd like to have just one sub and alias it for specific task.

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. What is the larger issue you are dealing with?

Comment: @mob edited question to address XY problem

Comment: If you need to know which alias was used then you shouldn't be using aliases. You need an additional parameter to the subroutine to convey the information you are hoping to pass in the subroutine alias used.

Comment: You haven't explained why you can't just use `&foo` in both places in the hash.

Comment: @Borodin because I can't then distinct, which task was caller

Comment: Okay, but you haven't explained why you need to be able to distinguish. This should be either two different subroutines or the same subroutine with a parameter, like `foo('x_y_z')` and `foo('a_b_c_d')`

Comment: @Borodin  I process tasks  based on database + table + action, and I can call `&{ $dispatch->{ $tb }{ $table }{ $task } }( $params )`, and mostly those result with specific subs. But on many cases the action needs just to know which db and table and task are involved.

Comment: Your question uses aliasing but your example uses references (to anonymous wrappers). Those are two very different things.

Comment: @Borodin calling in dispatch tree `foo( 'x_y_z', @_ )` solves my XY problem. Still, calling aliased sub problem is interesting ;)

Comment: @MichaelCarman in my second example anonymous sub-refs contain call to aliased subs. Question is about those.

Comment: *"calling aliased sub problem is interesting"* No, it's a misconception. You're trying to use the name of the alias as an additional parameter, and your comment makes it clear that all this has come about because you're trying to be "clever" by calling `&a_b_c_d` to pass the current contents of `@_`. Don't do that: write clear code instead. I'm surprised you're not using `goto &abcd` to mess with the call frame as well.

Comment: @Borodin calling it misconception refers that there is no meaningful use for that. In script-level I can introspect which name was used to call my script. And I find it useful. In subroutine- level, seems, I can't. My use-case may be poor, but knowing caller alias may have uses which make code better.

Comment: Don't have time to really read the question, much less post and answer right now, but [this](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1202098) might help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're trying to do is simply not possible within Perl's datamodel. An alias is just an alias, not an object with its own identity.

Note that it's possible to copy a subroutine and give it a new name, for example:

```
use Sub::Name;

*x_y_z = subname x_y_z => \&foo;
```

But you will have to do this manually.

It is not a good idea to depend on subnames for anything except for stack traces. Trying to build any logic on top of these names will likely end up in a hard to debug mess, not elegant software.

It might be better to pass the route name into the handler function as an explicit parameter, and to create a helper function to abstract over the necessary plumbing. For example:

```
my %routes;

sub route {
  my ($name, $handler) = @_;
  $routes{$name} = sub { $handler->($name => @_) };
  return;
}

sub common_handler { ... }

route a_b_c => \&common_handler;
route x_y_z => \&common_handler;
route foo_bar => sub {
  my ($route) = @_;
  say "Custom handler invoked for route $route";
};

$routes{$name}->(@args);
```

If absolutely necessary you can of course implement such a `route` function so that it installs the handlers as a named subroutine. But at that point you are building some kind of framework like Moo(se), not an ordinary Perl module.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. `foo_bar_baz` is an alias. `caller` reports the name of the subroutine as declared, not the name by which it was called. Note that not all subroutines have names and not all calls are by name. (Anonymous subs exist only as a `CODE` reference; they don't have an entry in the symbol table. Any sub—named or not—can be called via a reference.)

That said, you don't need aliasing here. What you really want is extra parameters for the database, table, etc., on which the sub should operate. The idiomatic way to do that is to wrap the generic sub and pass that information via the wrapper:

```
my %dispatch = (
    a => { b => { c => sub { foo('a', 'b', 'c', @_) } } },
    x => { y => { z => sub { foo('x', 'y', 'z', @_) } } },
);

$dispatch{a}{b}{c}->('foo');
$dispatch{x}{y}{z}->('bar');

sub foo {
    my $db     = shift;
    my $table  = shift;
    my $task   = shift;
    my @params = @_;
    say "$db $table $task: @params";
}
```

Comment: Can't understand, what you mean with "Such a name might not even exist"? Both `foo_bar_baz` and `x_y_z` live happily in symbol table.

Comment: @w.k: I was alluding to calls made via a `CODE` reference. I've revised my answer to make that clearer.